# Hide element depending by a condition

Tags: reactjs

I have an application, where depending by a condition i want to hide or to show data.
So, i added the condition:

```js
columnTitle:selectedRowKeys.length > 0? { selections: true }: { selections: false },
```

But the condition does not work. When i will click on a checkbox, i want to display `selections`, and when none of a checkbox is clicked, i want to hide the `selections`.

This is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-selection-ant-design-demo-mvy5j?file=/index.js:982-1017

How to solve the issue?

selections is this dropdown:
[image]

Comment: It's unclear to me. I really cannot get what you are trying to achieve here...
Something like that? https://codesandbox.io/s/000vqw38rl?file=/index.js

Comment: @MarekUrbanowicz, selections is a dropdown with data from `selections: [....]`. When i will click on a checkbox i want to show it, but by default it should be hidden

Comment: @MarekUrbanowicz, i updated the question with some information about, what is selection. Let me know if it is clear. Thanks

Comment: I dont see the selections drop down, where is that?

Comment: @kiranvj, now is ok? Please, let me know if the issue disappeared?

Comment: @AskMen I see it and I have added an answer

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this (false should also work instead of null)

```
columnTitle: selectedRowKeys.length > 0 ? true : null,
```

You can also do like this (double NOT to make it boolean)

```
columnTitle: !!selectedRowKeys.length,
```

instead of (what you have now.)

```
columnTitle:{selections : selectedRowKeys.length > 0 ? true : false},
```

Check this - https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-selection-ant-design-demo-g1u4f

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and It is working

```
columnTitle:selectedRowKeys.length > 0 ? false : true,
```

The full **rowSelection** object would be

```
  const rowSelection = {
      selectedRowKeys,
      onChange: this.onSelectChange,
      columnTitle:selectedRowKeys.length > 0 ? false : true,
      hideDefaultSelections: true,
      selections: [
        Table.SELECTION_ALL,
        Table.SELECTION_INVERT,
        {
          key: "odd",
          text: "Select Odd Row",
          onSelect: changableRowKeys => {
            let newSelectedRowKeys = [];
            newSelectedRowKeys = changableRowKeys.filter((key, index) => {
              if (index % 2 !== 0) {
                return false;
              }
              return true;
            });
            this.setState({ selectedRowKeys: newSelectedRowKeys });
          }
        },
        {
          key: "even",
          text: "Select Even Row",
          onSelect: changableRowKeys => {
            let newSelectedRowKeys = [];
            newSelectedRowKeys = changableRowKeys.filter((key, index) => {
              if (index % 2 !== 0) {
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            });
            this.setState({ selectedRowKeys: newSelectedRowKeys });
          }
        }
      ]
    };
```

[Try this](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-selection-ant-design-demo-uuqfs?file=/index.js)

Comment: it is what i want. Probably you know, how to add the next feature: when to click on a checkbox from a row, to display the dropdown icon (`selections`), not as a title of this column, but instead of `Name`,- title of next column? I checked the api, but i didn't find a solution. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
columnTitle:selectedRowKeys.length > 0? { selections: true }: { selections: false }
```

Try something like this

```
 columnTitle:{selections : selectedRowKeys.length > 0 ? true : false}
```

Comment: I am not sure about what you are trying to achieve, but the condition above works